# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.0 GiB for an array with shape (120, 12300000) and data type object

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a 40GB file in pandas and perform some operations on it.
I am using chunk, but getting MemoryError.
(RAM of System = 32 GB)

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv',low_memory = False, chunksize = 50000):
    df = df.append(chunk)
```

How should my code be in order to read the large file ?

Answer (score 3):

"You can't have a DataFrame larger than your machine's RAM."

https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-8-scaling.html

If you're reading 40GB file into 32GB of RAM, I don't think that'll work.  Can you perform your operations on the chunks themselves and save it instead of doing it on the entire dataset at once?

BTW, if you're build a DataFrame from chunks, rather than appending each chunk to the same DataFrame in each iteration, it'll be faster to collect them in a list and then concat them at the end.  Otherwise, Pandas has to create a new massive dataframe at each iteration.

```
dfs = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv',low_memory = False, chunksize = 50000):
    dfs.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: if i want to use `to_csv` when would i use it ? after `concat` or we can keep on appending chunks to new csv ?

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Comment: If your analysis can be performed on each chunk independently, then I would just perform the analysis on each chunk, append it to the csv, then move on to the next chunk.  Then you won't end up with memory errors from trying to hold the entire thing in memory.